# Error when subtracting two negative numbers in ksh: “assignment requires lvalue”

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am trying to debug someone else's script:

The code line is:

```
y=$((${oldvalue[$x]}-${newvalue[$x]}))
```

y gets calculated fine as long as both sides are positive numbers. However, I have a production situation where they are both negative and the error I get is:

```
DEBUG Old value = -4144290000
DEBUG New value = -4009685000
script.sh: line 123: -4144290000--4009685000: assignment requires lvalue
```

I never would use `ksh` myself for even the simplest of calculations but I am in a position of production support and have to deal with a big ball of mud, I would use at least Perl/Python. Can anybody tell why this problem is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It needed spaces on both sides of the minus

```
y=$((${oldvalue[$x]} - ${newvalue[$x]}))
```

Comment: that wasn't so hard now, was it? Will python or perl handle `-4144290000--4009685000` to your expectation? ;-) ... Good luck to all.